# Internet Connection Sharing and remote DHCP issue on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, networking, wireless-networking, dhcp, ics

Due to temporary lack of external WiFi access point I have started using ICS to share internet connections to my mobile devices from my laptop. I know basics to configure it and what services must be enabled and it works quite good. I would complaint about the power of WiFi compared to my last external access point but it is not important. My problem is that ICS DHCP somehow blocks external DHCP server located in LAN. So if ethernet adapter which shares connection to WiFi has to renew IP address i don't have internet connection anymore. If I set static IP there is no problem with connection but I move my laptop beetween work and home and it's annoying for me. From many approaches the only one I have found is to disable sharing in adapter settings or disable and reenable ICS service. I know there is no way to set priorities on different DHCPs but maybe there is some way to block ethernet adapter from getting IP from ICS service?

Comment: Offtopic but can anyone tell me why word hello is cutted from final post?

Comment: Internet Connection Sharing uses Network Address Translation (NAT) for the shared connection so your laptop will act as a DHCP server and router to your mobile devices and they will be located on a different subnet than your laptops ethernet adapter.

However, your question is very confusing and hard to follow, especially when you say the ethernet adapter is getting it's IP from the ICS service? It should always be getting it's IP from your modem/router.  Please clarify your question?

Comment: I can't clarify it more because i don't understand this as well. The problem is after changing main interface to DHCP mode from static, it can't get IP address from DHCP router. I need to disable ICS to get proper address, then I can enable ICS again. There is nothing in event log, except for short notification that main interface didn't get IP address. Other DHCP logs show nothing more. And if I check opened ports then port 68 is occupied by 192.168.137.1 which is ICS dhcp service.

Comment: Worth to mention this occupation is only on list when I tried to connect mobile device to laptop wifi. Otherwise its not on list of ports and external DHCP is working correctly even with ICS run.

Answer (score 0):

Most issues with ICS occur where the clients cannot get a DHCP address. However, you are stating that it's the host computer that cannot get an IP address.  This could be a possible winsock corruption or bad hostednetwork settings.  You can reset and reconfigure to see if this resolves your issue by opening an elevated command prompt and issuing:

```
netsh winsock reset
```

You can then also open regedit and delete the HostedNetworkSettings registry key located inside:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\WlanSvc\Parameters\HostedNetworkSettings\
```

Reboot afterwards, reconfigure and retest.

If that doesn't work, consider upgrading to Windows 10 if possible to use the Mobile Hotspot feature which is easier to configure and tends to be more reliable.

Other options would be to consider using a 3rd party application like [MyPublicWifi](https://www.mypublicwifi.com/publicwifi/en/index.html) or Connectify.  A final workaround would be to use a program like Netsetman (freeware) to create different static IP and DHCP profiles that will work in your scenario and then you can toggle between them quickly from the NetSetMan system tray icon.

Comment: MyPublicWifi seems nice and reliable. I will try it.